# Transit visa in Amsterdam

Tags: airports, amsterdam

I'm Philippine passport holder having tourist visa in UK and Turkey. I wish to travel Turkey from UK via Amsterdam. Do i require a transit visa to transit in Amsterdam?

Comment: Why not take a direct flight?

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Cheap fares?